# prevent my application from copy text of textview

Tags: android

In my application  textview text copy from Universal Copy app . Universal copy app download from play store.
I want to prevent copy text of textview in my application .Text copy only from Universal copy app.i want to prevent my application from universal copy app.

Is that possible?if possible than how can i do?

Note: i want to prevent copy text from Textview not for Edittext. And Textview copy via Univesal copy app.

Comment: you can draw your text on Canvas. Then it should be harder (not impossible) to copy it. Still possible using screenshot and OCR

Comment: Thank you for your answer .but still not working

Comment: Show what you did. Probably you did something wrong

Comment: yeah.. Its working.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
String ss = "My String";
textView.setText(ss);
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Option 2 (In your xml):

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textIsSelectable="true" <!-- Put this line into your textview -->
android:text="My String" />
```

Option 3 (Not recommended): Using webview instead of textview is much easier. But it is not recommended because of memory high consumption. But ıf you still want to do this your can to it like;

```
String ss = "My String";
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", ss, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: i tried android:textIsSelectable="true" this one but its not working